# AWS CodeDeploy appspec parse issue: invalid version value ()

Tags: visual-studio, amazon-web-services

I am trying to deploy a project, and I keep getting the following error:

`The deployment failed because an invalid version value () was entered in the application specification file. Make sure your AppSpec file specifies "0.0" as the version, and then try again.`

The spec file is down to the bare minimum (see below), has been created in Visual Studio, is properly named (appspec.yml) and formatted, as far as I can see, and is being executed by the latest version of the AWS CodeDeploy agent on Windows Server 2016. I've even tried making the line endings unix-style, no joy.

I do not see any valid reason why the agent should not be reading the version correctly.

```
version: 0.0
os: windows
files:
  - source: '\'
    destination: 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that Visual Studio saves files by default as UTF-8 with a Byte Order Mark (Visual Studio refers to it as a "signature") at the beginning.

The CodeDeploy agent was choking on the BOM. When I saved the file as straight UTF-8, the deployment was processed as expected.

It appears that this is a regression, and I've reported it as such, but it's worth documenting the issue and workaround until it is fixed (or in case it shows back up again in the future!)